# Stop Signing ClickOnce Manifest - After Certificate Expired and on new development machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I created a VB Win Forms app using VS2010 that used ClickOnce deployment.
Sign ClickOnce Manifests was checked. (VS created the certificate and I had no idea what the password was)
The Certificate Expired so I created a TemporaryKey.pfx (This expires in 1 year, and I have the password)
I was able to publish and deploy with the Temporary certificate.
I now have a new pc. I copied the solution folder from the old pc.
If I try to build the app I get the following error:

"Error 1   Cannot import the following key file: SimmStock_TemporaryKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_B3DF0282FC97BF34    SimmStock2"

I unchecked "Sign ClickOnce Manifests" and the application can build and run.

As soon as I try to Publish then "Sign ClickOnce Manifests" keeps changing to checked. and get the following error:

"Error  1   Cannot import the following key file: SimmStock_TemporaryKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_B3DF0282FC97BF34    SimmStock2
"

**Question**: How can I stop signing completely?